# Image store into file not Link

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

i got problem in firebase storage. I make a project there is no error with take picture and store it in firestore. The problem is that url image from phone path and not uploaded into firebase storage.Before this, its works and uploaded into firebase. Suddenly, few days later, the image not even uploaded into firebase storage.  When i see the firestore, its show the link of image was from phone storage. Can anyone Help me with this?

Im already edit my code.. but only sending it to firestore.. the error handler appear.

```
package my.wedee.com.wedeeon9bisnis;


                import android.Manifest;
                import android.content.Context;
                import android.content.Intent;
                import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
                import android.net.Uri;
                import android.os.Build;
                import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
                import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
                import android.text.TextUtils;
                import android.view.MenuItem;
                import android.view.MotionEvent;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
                import android.widget.Button;
                import android.widget.EditText;
                import android.widget.ProgressBar;
                import android.widget.Toast;

                import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
                import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
                import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
                import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
                import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
                import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
                import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
                import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
                import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
                import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
                import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
                import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

                import java.util.HashMap;
                import java.util.Map;

                import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

                public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


                    private EditText fullNameOwner, emailBiz, locationBiz;
                    private CircleImageView profileImage;
                    private Button SaveInformation;
                    private ProgressBar progressBar;

                    private Uri mainImageURI = null;

                    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
                    private StorageReference storageReference;
                    private FirebaseFirestore mFireStore;

                    private String currentUserId;

                    private Boolean isChanged = false;
                    private Uri download_uri;

                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);


                        //firebase
                        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


                        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarEditProfile);

                        //toolbar
                        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarEditInfo); // get the reference of Toolbar
                        toolbar.setTitle("Account Personal Info"); // set Title for Toolbar
                        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // Setting/replace toolbar as the ActionBar

                        // add back arrow to toolbar
                        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                        }


                        //findviewbyID
                        fullNameOwner = findViewById(R.id.editTextFullnameBiz);
                        emailBiz = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailBiz);
                        locationBiz = findViewById(R.id.editTextLocationBiz);
                        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profile_image_edit);
                        SaveInformation = findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveInfoEdit);


                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mFireStore.collection("Profile On9Biz").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    if (task.getResult().exists()) {

                                        String fullname = task.getResult().getString("fullname");
                                        String email = task.getResult().getString("email");
                                        String location = task.getResult().getString("location");
                                        String image = task.getResult().getString("profile_images");

                                        mainImageURI = Uri.parse(image);


                                        fullNameOwner.setText(fullname);
                                        emailBiz.setText(email);
                                        locationBiz.setText(location);

                                        RequestOptions placeholderRequest = new RequestOptions();
                                        placeholderRequest.placeholder(R.drawable.profile);

                                        Glide.with(EditProfileActivity.this).setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest).load(image).into(profileImage);

                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                    }


                                } else {


                                    String errorMsg = task.getException().getMessage();
                                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Firebase Error :" + errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }


                            }
                        });


                        SaveInformation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                final String full_nameBiz = fullNameOwner.getText().toString().trim();
                                final String email_Ob = emailBiz.getText().toString().trim();
                                final String location_Ob = locationBiz.getText().toString().trim();


                                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(full_nameBiz) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email_Ob) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(location_Ob) && mainImageURI != null) {


                                    StorageReference image_path = storageReference.child("profile_images").child(currentUserId + ".jpg");
                                    image_path.putFile(mainImageURI);
                                    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                download_uri = task.getResult();

                                                StoreFireStore(task,full_nameBiz,email_Ob,location_Ob);

                                            } else {

                                                String errorMsg = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error :" + errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {


                                            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    });
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                }

                            }
                        });


                        profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {


                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Permission Denied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EditProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                                    } else {

                                        BringImagePicker();


                                    }

                                } else {

                                    BringImagePicker();


                                }

                            }
                        });


                    }

                    private void StoreFireStore(@NonNull Task<Uri> task, String full_nameBiz, String email_Ob, String location_Ob) {

                        Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                        userMap.put("fullname", full_nameBiz);
                        userMap.put("email", email_Ob);
                        userMap.put("location", location_Ob);
                        userMap.put("profile_images", download_uri.toString());

                        mFireStore.collection("Profile On9Biz").document(currentUserId).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Data Has Been Stored..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    SentToProfile();

                                } else {

                                    String errorMsg = task.getException().getMessage();
                                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Firebase Error :" + errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                }

                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }

                        });



                    }


                    private void SentToProfile() {


                        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(nextIntent);
                    }


                    @Override
                    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                                mainImageURI = result.getUri();
                                profileImage.setImageURI(mainImageURI);


                            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

                                Exception error = result.getError();
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Error :" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }

                    }


                    //hidekeyboard
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                        return true;
                    }


                    //backButton
                    @Override
                    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        // handle arrow click here
                        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                            SentToProfile(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
                        }

                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                    }


                    private void BringImagePicker() {


                        CropImage.activity()
                                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                                .start(EditProfileActivity.this);


                    }
                }
```

[image: See that image its show the link in firestore from the image i cropped, tell me how can i fix this]

Here is my firebase Storage rules...

```
        service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
      }
    }
```

and here is my Firestore Rules :-

```
    service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
   }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the download URL for the image you do:

```
download_uri = storageReference.getDownloadUrl().getResult();
```

Unfortunately that may not work, since the download URL may not be available yet. If you look at the [documentation for `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) it says:

> `public Task<Uri> getDownloadUrl ()`
>
> Asynchronously retrieves a long lived download URL with a revokable token.

So you're not getting a URL, but a `Task` that asynchronously returns the URL. To get the actual URL, you need to attach a completion listener to the task:

```
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            download_uri = task.getResult();
            // TODO: write the download_uri to the database here
        }
    }
```

For a longer example, see the [Firebase Storage documentation on getting the download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url).

Comment: im try your suggestion, but i put it in different method.. it show an error. I dont know where should i put that codes.. because im totally newbie..

Comment: i got an error when i put the firebase firestore in the task.is successful.. also when i run i got  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference..

Comment: i got an error by that error handler.. its say "user didnt get the permission"  in my firebase rules i already make the rules for it... service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Please add your rules to your question. In general have a look at [how to create a minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is the best way to get help in code-related questions.

Comment: i already edit my post.. as you can see..i only got error from the error handler. the image already uploaded.. but now the all the data didnt not inserted into firestore.. sorry for my bad explaination..

Comment: tq. The image uploaded to firestore now. But , it cannot load.  it says java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/authwarisan.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Ftap3U7pG4tdK45fySzkXzvqpOC12.jpg?alt=media&token=329ac568-6d5a-43f2-a793-9589063be6d3)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
String reviewPost = editReview.getText().toString().trim();
String userName = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getDisplayName();
Uri profileImage = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();

//Log.e("Image", "User Image" + userImage);
            String uId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
bookReviewUser = new HashMap<>();
bookReviewUser.put("ReviewId",uId);
bookReviewUser.put("ReviewPost",reviewPost);
bookReviewUser.put("UserName",username);
bookReviewUser.put("UserImage",profileImage.toString());
bookReviewUser.put("Date",new Timestamp(new Date()));
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Review").document(userName)
                    .set(bookReviewUser)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                        }
                    });
};
```